# Android Horizontal Snapping scrollable RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there any solution for my question?

I am currently using SnapHelper but the result is like this.

[Snapping RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkaTe.gif)

As you can see, the scrollview can't stop in the first item but other items already able to center focus when scrolling. How to achieve center focus of every items?

Code:

```
public class ScrollingSnap1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling_snap1);
        arraylist.add("1111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
        arraylist.add("2222222222222222222222222");
        arraylist.add("3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333");
        arraylist.add("99999999");
        arraylist.add("1010101010101001010101010");
        Adapter1 adapter1 = new Adapter1(arraylist);
        RecyclerView recyclerview = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler2);
        SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter1);
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerview);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply use `RecyclerView` with horizontal scrolling using `LayoutManager`.

Comment: @Piyush I already set as horizontal scrolling, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

In order to center the first and the last items, you need to create extra space at the beginning and end of your RecyclerView. An easy way to do so is to use an ItemDecoration, like so:

```kotlin
class BoundsOffsetDecoration : ItemDecoration() {
    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect,
                                view: View,
                                parent: RecyclerView,
                                state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)

        val itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)

        // It is crucial to refer to layoutParams.width (view.width is 0 at this time)!
        val itemWidth = view.layoutParams.width
        val offset = (parent.width - itemWidth) / 2

        if (itemPosition == 0) {
            outRect.left = offset
        } else if (itemPosition == state.itemCount - 1) {
            outRect.right = offset
        }
    }
}
```